# How a collabarator can add files git hub repository?

Tags: git, github

I have created an git hub repository and have added a collaborator to this repository.

How can this collaborator add files to git hub repository.

Comment: By `clone`ing, making changes, `add`ing, `commit`ing, and `push`ing (same as any git repo) would be the simplest way...

Comment: Thank You Mark Adelsberger.